# DS.AdapterError.extend fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

based on documentation https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.AdapterError.html I am trying to duplicate.

my code :

```
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.AdapterError.extend({ message: "Down for maintenance." });
```

but I just get errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: _emberData.default.AdapterError.extend is not a function
```

has anyone extended this error object? I ma truly just capturing 401,403 errors that happen during the ember-data transaction. I wanted to use some custom errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you hit a snag in the documentation. The code you are wanting to use is actually behind a feature flag which will enable that functionality ... Apparently the build tools for API docs aren't handling that right (or the docs weren't feature flagged properly).

See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/FEATURES.md and https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.12.0/addon/adapters/errors.js#L11 for further details.

Comment: interesting. since my project is being upgraded I did not get the features.json file that is mentioned. I will look this over but it definitely is what I was looking for

Comment: Unless you are on a beta or canary build, you won't be able to enable that.  But you should be able to do things as mentioned here to experiment with it: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/contributing/adding-new-features/#toc_builds

Comment: oops. forgot to click that button. my bad :)